# Best index for sorted list of dictionary words

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with two coluns: ID sequence, and 'word' which is list of German words (sorted by `sort` command, and then COPY'ied):

```
Aachen
Aachener
Aachenerin
Aachenerinnen
Aachenern
Aacheners
Aachens
```

The goal is to list all words that contain certain string, f.i.:

```
SELECT word FROM german_words WHERE word ~ 'chen';
```

For 'word' column I used normal unique index, and such queries take 1 to 2 seconds (1.9M rows). Is there an indexing strategy in PostgreSQL that could make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of queries, the following index would be optimum:

```
CREATE INDEX ON words USING gin (word gin_trgm_ops);
```

This requires that you install the [`pg_trgm` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html).

From the documentation:

> F.31.4. Index Support
>
> The pg_trgm module provides GiST and GIN index operator classes that allow you to create an index over a text column for the purpose of **very fast similarity searches**. These index types support the above-described similarity operators, and additionally support **trigram-based index searches for LIKE, ILIKE, ~ and ~* queries**.

---

The execution plan you're likely to get is the following one:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                |
|  1 | Bitmap Heap Scan on words  (cost=20.47..70.73 rows=60 width=36) (actual time=0.147..0.432 rows=182 loops=1)               |
|  2 |   Recheck Cond: (word ~ 'chen'::text)                                                                                     |
|  3 |   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2                                                                                        |
|  4 |   Heap Blocks: exact=42                                                                                                   |
|  5 |   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on words_word_idx  (cost=0.00..20.45 rows=60 width=0) (actual time=0.129..0.129 rows=184 loops=1) |
|  6 |         Index Cond: (word ~ 'chen'::text)                                                                                 |
|  7 | Planning time: 0.133 ms                                                                                                   |
|  8 | Execution time: 0.476 ms                                                                                                  |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[You can check it at Rextester here](http://rextester.com/TOFL19543)

Comment: I am not 100% sure you can use `unaccent` as it is, because it's designed to work with the full-text-search dictionnaries. But you can most probably use something like [`translate`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), and do something like `translate(accented_word, 'àèìòùáéíóúäëïöü', 'aeiouaeiouaeiou')` which the character you need... both on the `words` from your table and the sequence of characters you want to match. I'd use a specific column `unaccented_word` where I would store the computed info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great answer, comment and useful tips!

Comment: I was able to combine unaccent with your solution. The difference in performance is huge, I am happy :)

Comment: Glad to have helped!